# Убрать компоненты из URL средстами php (не htaccess)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Этот код отрезает заданные! параметры url. Подскажите как сделать так чтобы он отрезал все возможные параметры, о которых я еще не знаю.
Спасибо.

```
<?php

function remove_key($key,$key1,$key2) {
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $vars);
    $url = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') . http_build_query(array_diff_key($vars,array($key=>"",$key1=>"",$key2=>"")));
    return $url;
}

 echo remove_key ('cur_cc','tag','curPos','_utl_t','amp','id','cur_','yclid');?>
```

Comment: А зачем "отрезать"? Может правильнее - получать необходимое?

Comment: дело в том что мне нужно получить ссылку без параметров, это цель.

Comment: якобы, есть решение в strtok($url, '?') но либо у меня не работает, либо я не правильно это использую

Comment: мне кажется ключ есть в самой функции. так есть key и их количество, может их заменить на "любое" количество и "любое" значение?

Comment: кстати, echo не правильно написано, уберутся из url только первые 3 параметра

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function remove_key($url) {
    $arr = explode('/', $url);
    array_pop($arr);

    return join('/', $arr);
}

$url = 'site.ru/папка/папка/?cur_cc=1159&tag=письмо&curPos=90';

echo remove_key($url);

/*
site.ru/папка/папка
*/
```

Comment: @samurai79, оформил код в виде функции.

Comment: да, тольно задача не в этом

Comment: изначальный адрес http://www.site.ru/des3/?cur_cc=1159&tag=письмо&curPos=90 а мне нужно получить http://www.site.ru/des3/ тоесть урл без хвоста

Comment: @samurai79, я вас не правильно понял? -- покажите пожалуйста, как должна выглядеть результирующая строка(или массив)

Comment: есть site.ru/папка/папка/?всякий хвостиз параметров разных а ссылка должна получиться site.ru/папка/папка/

Comment: @samurai79, переписал код в своем посту, теперь то что вам нужно?

Comment: А вот это уже очень интересно, в примере все получилось.

Comment: Спасибо! огромное

Comment: теперь пойду вставлять динамический адрес в урл но думаю с этим справлюсь

Comment: все четко работает. спасибо еще раз большое, сам бы не смог